# What are good sources to learn the Torre Attack?

Tags: opening, 1.d4, kings-indian

I am particularly interested in the Torre Attack against the King's Indian formation.  What dvd or books, etc. are good, or is it best to dig up old games and Chess Informants?

Answer (score 4):

One of the books of the "Move By Move" series is about the [Torre Attack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1857446860). It's written by IM Palliser and published in 2012, so it's still relatively recent.

Digging up old games is definitely a good idea when studying an opening, but you can also find interesting material from recent games. This year, Kramnik played the Torre Attack against the King's Indian a couple of times: in blitz ([Kramnik - Vachier-Lagrave](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1879804)) and rapid ([Kramnik - Nepomniachtchi](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1879651)), but also in classical time control ([Kramnik - Radjabov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1872036)).